# Trying to start multiple .exe files in order with a bat file but first line fails and second line is successful

Tags: batch-file, cmd

My code in the .bat looks like this.

```
"C:\users\reshade injector.exe"
C:\pathtogame\game.exe "added argument"
```

"c:\users\reshade injector.exe" <- if I open the actual file, it opens a command window and waits for my other application to launch. Is this a console app?

C:\pathtogame\game.exe "added argument" <- this works and launches my game

Another issue is that when launching the first .exe, a command window stays open. How do I make the command window not appear?

Can anyone help me with these two problems?

*edit for clarity
by opening the actual file, I mean double-clicking on the original reshade injector.exe.
When opening reshade injector.exe, two cmd windows open. They close as soon as I launch the game.exe.

I can't seem to get the reshade injector.exe to launch through the .bat file.

Comment: When you use the point-click-and-giggle method of executing a batch, the batch window will close if a syntax-error is found or the script runs to completion. You *can* put a `pause` after statements and home in on the error, but better to [open a 'command prompt'](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/) and run your batch from there so that the window remains open and any (error) messages will be displayed. It's likely that the batch will generate an error message when it attempts to run `reshade inhector`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batch will run any application it finds. If the application does not terminate (eg. it's waiting for user-input) then it will progress to the next instruction.

Some applications work by launching another (the user-interface) and then terminating, leaving the second application resident.

There's no way to tell without observing which approach any random application may take.

So - your batch *should* execute a file named `c:\users\reshade injector.exe`.

You say that "fails". Is there an error message generated? You would likely need to run the batch from the "command prompt" to see that message. Note that the <kbd>Space</kbd> between `reshade` and `injector` must be in the actual filename. If `injector.exe` is a file in a subdirectory called `reshade`, then you need a backslash between `reshade` and `injector`.

Having resolved the actual name of the first executable, try

```
@echo off
setlocal
start "" "firstexecutablename"
start "" "secondexecutablename" "arguments"
```

The first two lines prevent "command echoing" which  is used for debugging and establish a "local environment" which ensures the "environment" for the batch file remains unchanged when the batch terminates. In the current case, these two lines are probably unnecessary, but it's SOP for batch files.

The batch should then close its session and window once it has attempted to launch the two applications.

The `""` following `start` becomes the window-title. It can be any quoted string you like, but should not be omitted as `start` uses the first quoted string it finds as a window-title and may not recognise it as part of the executable/arguments.

Comment: Hi thank you this solved my first problem of the cmd window staying open. 
I'm still not sure why the reshade injector.exe does not want to launch.
I see cmd windows opening and closing, and then I guess it moves on to the next line, which launches game.exe. BUT the outcome is that reshade injector.exe did not actually work.

Comment: In your original code, try adding a `pause` line after the first line, `"C:\users\reshade injector.exe"`. When you execute the batch, a window should remain open with a response that could explain why `reshade injector` failed.

Comment: oh my gosh. So I did what you said and added the pause after the first line in the original code. 
Cmd came up with the first line of code displayed on it but I noticed that the cmd window opens up, pointing to the location where my .bat file is located; which is my desktop. 
So i thought to move the .bat to the folder where the reshade injector.exe is located and now it works! 
Thank you!